# What are the cartoony graphics on landing pages called

Tags: website-design, landing-page, graphics

Many landing pages have some sort of cartoony wacky caricatures depicting humans. *What are they called?*.

I mean characters like the ones [here](https://colorlib.com/preview/#imagine), [here](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fimage.freepik.com%2Ffree-vector%2Fcartoon-virtual-reality-landing-page-illustration_2095-76.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.freepik.com%2Fpremium-vector%2Fcartoon-virtual-reality-landing-page-illustration_4025407.htm&tbnid=_xUgsTNyX0eykM&vet=12ahUKEwjQzIaNv-vrAhUhgHMKHS1IA1MQMygDegUIARCnAQ..i&docid=2CVU7bkQKS0d9M&w=626&h=391&q=landing%20page%20cartoon&ved=2ahUKEwjQzIaNv-vrAhUhgHMKHS1IA1MQMygDegUIARCnAQ), [here](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fi.graphicmama.com%2Fblog%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F10%2F26113618%2Ffinaguru-landing.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fgraphicmama.com%2Fblog%2Flanding-page-examples%2F&tbnid=_6_p1rxtSlDhRM&vet=12ahUKEwjQzIaNv-vrAhUhgHMKHS1IA1MQMygAegUIARCgAQ..i&docid=9WwAhJYZ-cSbNM&w=910&h=426&q=landing%20page%20cartoon&ved=2ahUKEwjQzIaNv-vrAhUhgHMKHS1IA1MQMygAegUIARCgAQ), [here](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn5.vectorstock.com%2Fi%2F1000x1000%2F89%2F89%2Farchitect-planning-cartoon-landing-page-vector-22908989.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.vectorstock.com%2Froyalty-free-vector%2Farchitect-planning-cartoon-landing-page-vector-22908989&tbnid=6YQgjfh36RbZaM&vet=12ahUKEwjQzIaNv-vrAhUhgHMKHS1IA1MQMygKegUIARC1AQ..i&docid=i8_l-d_niik6-M&w=1000&h=780&q=landing%20page%20cartoon&ved=2ahUKEwjQzIaNv-vrAhUhgHMKHS1IA1MQMygKegUIARC1AQ)

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean, *what are they called*... drawings, images, cartoons, landing pages... take your pick. Why do you think they have a special name?

Comment: @musefan Because they all look very similar.Bright colored, no facial features, smooth skin etc.For example, I dont see the type of cartoons in like sci-fi movies,  artistic sketches etcon landing pages.tHAT is why I think they are called somthing in partcular

Comment: @musefan Also, all I want to know is what word do I google to get those particular kinds of pictures

Comment: I think it is a valid question, but maybe not for this site. Please try asking this question here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search for "character vector illustration", you can easily find similar images.
There are some free sources of quality illustrations:

https://www.drawkit.io/

https://blush.design

https://stories.freepik.com/?ref=lapaninja

Comment: Been 3 years. Forgot to say thank you. You helped a lot